In Visual Studio 2022 Git Changes window, how to I trim / remove branches from the list of local branches?
I don't want to delete the branches, and this list is obviously "curated" somehow, as when I do a fresh install of VS on a new machine, it's empty, and new branches are added to the list as I check them out. But they are never removed from the list, how do I remove branches from the list of local branches in Visual Studio 2022 Git Changes window without deleting the git branch?


right click and press delete it will only get rid of the local

Wat, you're kidding, I can't believe it's that simple! I always assumed it would delete the whole branch

hahahah no problem I actually also didn't know before your question, i thought I'll just try to do that

I kinda wish I could mass delete, since I have a bunch of old branches, but this works.

Hmm, actually, this delete method deletes the branches locally as well, but that doesn't really impact the branch on the origin, I could still switch to old branches again by selecting them from origin. So I can also clean up this list with the cmd git branch -d name1 name2 name3 etc.. to delete multiple branches locally. I guess I never bothered to understand how branches work in terms of deleting them locally. I thought it was permanent.
